# Executing The Same Command In Multiple Shell Scripts

Tags: linux, shell, file, automation

I'm using the following to to tee output of a command into a file:

```
logs/`basename $0`-`basename $1`.`date +%F--%R\`.log
```

And since this same syntax belongs in several different shell scripts, I'd really like it to only appear once.  My first thought was to put it in another shell script:

```
export LOGFILE=logs/`basename $0`-`basename $1`.`date +%F--%R`.log
# OR
export LOGFILE=logs/\`basename $0\`-\`basename $1\`.\`date +%F--%R\`.log
```

And have each file call the command like this:

```
java CMD | tee $LOGFILE
```

However this doesn't work.  Is there any way to describe a file to create in the way you see above only once but be able to reference it repeatedly in scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to define a function in the shell script...

But you almost have it working with the export.  If you want to keep going with that, the key is to escape out the $'s so they don't get replaced with their values until you're ready.  Then use `eval` to re-evaluate it later.

E.g.:

```
501 ~$ export foo='$bar'
502 ~$ echo $foo
$bar
503 ~$ export bar=moo
504 ~$ eval echo $foo
moo
505 ~$ export bar=hello
506 ~$ eval echo $foo
hello
```

Answer (score 1):

If your shell supports defining functions (e.g., bash, korn, etc.) then you could put it in a function and have each script include/import/whatever that file that the function is in.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that exporting the `LOGFILE` variable does not work, is that `$0` and `$1` don't have useful values at that point (`$0` is probably your shell's executable, and `$1` is probably nothing). One possibility would be a wrapper script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
LOGFILE="logs/`basename $0`-`basename $1`.`date +%F--%R`.log"
"$@" | tee "$LOGFILE"
```

Anything that you would otherwise pipe to tee, you now pass as arguments to the wrapper script. For example (assuming it was named new-tee) `new-tee java CMD` or for testing, `new-tee echo "hello world"`.

Answer (score 0):

After examining my specific curcumstances further, I think the best thing I can do is stop using bash and upgrade to a more powerful scripting language like Python.  Ethan's answer does indicate my problem can be resolved in Bash, but I would suggest to anyone looking to do what I'm doing that they examine if there's not a simpler way to do what they're doing, or if their problem might be better handled in Python.

Comment: Or perl, or ruby, etc.  I'm an old fart and like the challenge of shell scripts.